# Highcharts x-range datetime not shwoing with "Date.UTC(2023, 6, 20)"

Tags: javascript, highcharts, datetime-format

I am using Highcharts x-range to show data in date range.
the graph is not showing with quotes `""` for startdate (x) and enddate(x2).

```
"x": "Date.UTC(2018, 8, 18)",
"x2": "Date.UTC(2023, 6, 20)",
```

Sample Code added in JS fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/w1b6atc8/

no luck with Date.parse.

Answer (score 0):

In the notation:

```
"x": "Date.UTC(2018, 8, 18)",
"x2": "Date.UTC(2023, 6, 20)",
```

values for `x` and `x2` are just strings. You need to provide dates as millisecond timestamps.

```
"x": Date.UTC(2018, 8, 18),
"x2": Date.UTC(2023, 6, 20),
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9721csob/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.xrange.data

Comment: As a backend api response getting as a string. Not able to convert to millisecond timestamps.

Comment: Hi @Pavan, I understand that you can't change the received data structure, right? If so, you can convert dates to the valid format in this way: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1topw0cd/